# Is XSS exploit always illegal?

Tags: exploit, xss

I recently got a great deal of $$ stolen by scammers.  I am trying to use XSS exploitation to find his real identity (IMSI, IMEI, External IP, Internal IP, any computer unique ID)  Is it legal?   I am not going to hack his computer / phone, and I am not going to steal any password.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a purely legal question. [law.se] is more suitable for this kind of questions but note that  question of legality depends on the context and where you live.

Comment: This question is everyone who does exploitation / security expert needs to know.  Although it can be country specific, but remember "Internet" is cross country and laws in developed countries is more or less similar.

Comment: *"This question is everyone who does exploitation / security expert needs to know."* - there are lot of other questions these need to know which does not mean that all such questions are automatically on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

When you're not sure if something is legal, it's best to not do it. We aren't lawyers, you shouldn't trust our analysis if what is and isn't legal.  Even if it was in a grey area there's a good chance it could be a pain while the legal system sorted it out.

The [CFAA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) is likely the law you would run afowl of.

You can report [fraud and crime to the FBI](https://www.fbi.gov/scams-and-safety/common-fraud-schemes/internet-fraud)

Don't take the law into your own hands. There a chance you will do more harm than good.

Comment: I 98% believe it is legal but not 100% certain.  Therefore, would like to know how we IT workers can protect ourselves.